# ログイン状態の維持について

Tags: session

セッション管理についての質問です。
ログイン状態を維持し続けるには、セッションを保つ以外にユーザーを識別してDBからその情報を取得するなどを行っているのでしょうか。
どなたか教えていただけますでしょうか。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: ここでいう「ログイン状態を維持し続ける」とはいわゆるログイン時に設定する「ログインをしたままにするチェックボックス」の機能のことですか？それとも通常のセッションを利用したログイン維持のことですか？

Answer (score -3, accepted):

例えば、認証チケットを認証クッキーに入れてやり取りする場合は、認証クッキーとその中の認証チケットの有効期限を長く設定しておくという方法があります。

ブラウザのクッキーを削除すると再びログインする必要があるサイトの場合は、たぶん認証クッキーを使っていると思われます。